Whats the difference between calling functions through context menu with invoking verb with powershell?
Inspired by this question Programmatically managing windows frequent folder, i'm using the following powershell script to managing my window frequent folder.
$o = new-object -com shell.application
$o.Namespace('c:\My Folder').Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")

It used to work well, until some latest windows version about win10 and win11, just stucked forever.
Even worse, i'm not able to stop it or detect it until i closed the terminal window like what i described here How to stop a fully stuck powershell script when keyboard interrupt and Stop-Job not working?.
However, i have checked the related registries between two versions of windows and found them are same. Which means, i believe, windows have deeply disable it inside their core system.
But we can still do the same thing through windows context menu, through registry like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}\shell\pintohome or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.PinToHome?
So what's the difference between this two method? If they both call some internal function to do the same thing, can we use some different way to do it like through registry?

Works fine, I can't reproduce, I'm currently on Windows 11 24H2. It may be due to some 3rd party extension you've  installed on your PC.

This is not a scripting issue but a constant battle between Microsoft and automation engineers that littely try to take a shortcut to pin items to home or the taskbar where Microsoft wants to force "the user to approve the request." . See: Pin your app to the taskbar. As you pointed out yourself: Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10 shows some alternatives but if you get this to work, it might be broken again with the next update.

@SimonMourier sorry for not test on a pure system. i did check on a win11 24H2 vm, and the script works well. I will check it carefully to see whats the cause. Thanks for your response.

@iRon seems to need a better way to do it, thanks for your response.
